# How to install virtual box.tar gz on ubuntu 14.04 using terminal?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I have a downloaded copy of virtual box.tar from oracle. I couldn't find INSTALL/INSTALL.txt or README file in the extracted folder.How do I install it through terminal?

Comment: Why not install using the instructions given at https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the .tar. Instead, download the .deb here: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.22/virtualbox-5.0_5.0.22-108108~Ubuntu~trusty_amd64.deb. Then run:

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox*.deb
```

Comment: Thank you the reply. It worked.  Can you please tell me why did u put the * after 'virtualbox' ?

Comment: The [ * ] is a wildcard. I.e. dpkg will select the virtualbox-[version].deb you have downloaded ................... `cd Downloads/ && sudo dpkg -i virtualbox*.deb` .  .... Alternatively, just click the package, and it will be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. cd to extracted directory in terminal
2. run the following commands

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can add th VirtualBox repositorys to your sources list. This eases installation as you only need to run apt-get to install it. This would also insure that your VirtualBox is always up to date.

Go to your sources list located at /etc/apt/sources.list

> sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

Go down to the bottom and add the following line:

> deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib

Replace xenial with the name of the distro you are using eg. xenial for Ubuntu 16.04, trusty for Ubuntu 14.04 etc.

Save the changes and run:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install virtualbox

If everything goes well you should have VirtualBox installed on your system.